# ConvertTo-Csv Output without quotes

Tags: powershell, csv

I am using `ConvertTo-Csv` to get comma separated output

```
get-process | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
```

It outputs like:

```
"__NounName","Name","Handles","VM","WS",".....
```

However I would like to get output without quotes, like

```
__NounName,Name,Handles,VM,WS....
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a way to remove the quotes

```
get-process | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | % {$_ -replace '"',''}
```

But it has a serious drawback if one of the item contains a `"` it will be removed !

Comment: This is likely not applicable to the output of `get-process`, but this solution will also unescape fields that have special characters in them.  (e.g. "aaa","bbb","cc,cc","ddd").

Comment: @SteveGuidi Your are right, it's written in the answer.

Answer (score 25):

Hmm, I have Powershell 7 preview 1 on my mac, and `Export-Csv` has a `-UseQuotes` option that you can set to `AsNeeded`.  :)

Comment: That's not helpful for older versions of PowerShell.  It appears [Kory Gill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647567/639580) works best in that case.

Answer (score 11):

I was working on a table today and thought about this very question as I was previewing the CSV file in notepad and decided to see what others had come up with. It seems many have over-complicated the solution.
Here's a real simple way to remove the quote marks from a CSV file generated by the Export-Csv cmdlet in PowerShell.

**Create a TEST.csv file with the following data.**

"ID","Name","State"
"5","Stephanie","Arizona"
"4","Melanie","Oregon"
"2","Katie","Texas"
"8","Steve","Idaho"
"9","Dolly","Tennessee"

**Save As:  TEST.csv**

**Store file contents in a $Test variable**
`$Test = Get-Content .\TEST.csv`

**Load $Test variable to see results of the get-content cmdlet**
`$Test`

**Load $Test variable again and replace all ( "," ) with a comma, then trim start and end by removing each quote mark**

```
$Test.Replace('","',",").TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"')
```

**Save/Replace TEST.csv file**

```
$Test.Replace('","',",").TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') | Out-File .\TEST.csv -Force -Confirm:$false
```

**Test new file Output with Import-Csv and Get-Content:**

```
Import-Csv .\TEST.csv
Get-Content .\TEST.csv
```

**To Sum it all up, the work can be done with 2 lines of code**

```
$Test = Get-Content .\TEST.csv
$Test.Replace('","',",").TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') | Out-File .\TEST.csv -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty similar to the accepted answer but it helps to prevent unwanted removal of "real" quotes.

```
$delimiter = ','
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $_ -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }
```

This will do the following:

- Remove quotes that begin a line
- Remove quotes that end a line
- Replace quotes that wrap a delimiter with the delimiter alone.

Therefore, the only way this would go wrong is if one of the values actually contained not only quotes, but specifically a quote-delimiter-quote sequence, which hopefully should be pretty uncommon.

Comment: This does not work if the data you are working with was quoted because it contained a delimiter.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue, found this question, but was not satisfied with the answers because they all seem to suffer if the data you are using contains a delimiter, which should remain quoted.  Getting rid of the unneeded double quotes is a good thing.

The solution below appears to solve this issue for a general case, and for all variants that would cause issues.

I found this answer elsewhere, [Removing quotes from CSV created by PowerShell](http://www.sqlmovers.com/removing-quotes-from-csv-created-by-powershell/), and have used it to code up an example answer for the SO community.

**Attribution:**  *Credit for the regex, goes 100% to Russ Loski.*

**Code in a Function, Remove-DoubleQuotesFromCsv**

```
function Remove-DoubleQuotesFromCsv
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $InputFile,

        [string]
        $OutputFile
    )

    if (-not $OutputFile)
    {
        $OutputFile = $InputFile
    }

    $inputCsv = Import-Csv $InputFile

    $quotedData = $inputCsv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

    $outputCsv = $quotedData | % {$_ -replace  `
        '\G(?<start>^|,)(("(?<output>[^,"]*?)"(?=,|$))|(?<output>".*?(?<!")("")*?"(?=,|$)))' `
        ,'${start}${output}'}

    $outputCsv | Out-File $OutputFile -Encoding utf8 -Force
}
```

**Test Code**

```
$csvData = @"
id,string,notes,number
1,hello world.,classic,123
2,"a comma, is in here","test data 1",345
3,",a comma, is in here","test data 2",346
4,"a comma, is in here,","test data 3",347
5,"a comma, is in here,","test data 4`r`nwith a newline",347
6,hello world2.,classic,123
"@

$data = $csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv
"`r`n---- data ---"
$data

$quotedData = $data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"`r`n---- quotedData ---"
$quotedData

# this regular expression comes from:
# http://www.sqlmovers.com/removing-quotes-from-csv-created-by-powershell/
$fixedData = $quotedData | % {$_ -replace  `
  '\G(?<start>^|,)(("(?<output>[^,"\n]*?)"(?=,|$))|(?<output>".*?(?<!")("")*?"(?=,|$)))' `
  ,'${start}${output}'}
"`r`n---- fixedData ---"
$fixedData

$fixedData | Out-File e:\test.csv -Encoding ascii -Force
"`r`n---- e:\test.csv ---"
Get-Content e:\test.csv
```

**Test Output**

```
---- data ---

id string               notes                       number
-- ------               -----                       ------
1  hello world.         classic                     123   
2  a comma, is in here  test data 1                 345   
3  ,a comma, is in here test data 2                 346   
4  a comma, is in here, test data 3                 347   
5  a comma, is in here, test data 4...              347   
6  hello world2.        classic                     123   

---- quotedData ---
"id","string","notes","number"
"1","hello world.","classic","123"
"2","a comma, is in here","test data 1","345"
"3",",a comma, is in here","test data 2","346"
"4","a comma, is in here,","test data 3","347"
"5","a comma, is in here,","test data 4
with a newline","347"
"6","hello world2.","classic","123"

---- fixedData ---
id,string,notes,number
1,hello world.,classic,123
2,"a comma, is in here",test data 1,345
3,",a comma, is in here",test data 2,346
4,"a comma, is in here,",test data 3,347
5,"a comma, is in here,","test data 4
with a newline","347"
6,hello world2.,classic,123

---- e:\test.csv ---
id,string,notes,number
1,hello world.,classic,123
2,"a comma, is in here",test data 1,345
3,",a comma, is in here",test data 2,346
4,"a comma, is in here,",test data 3,347
5,"a comma, is in here,","test data 4
with a newline","347"
6,hello world2.,classic,123
```

Comment: [An answer by LCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50415379/1026) notes that this removes quotes also for cells containing the line separator \r\n

Comment: Edited answer to include suggestion from @LCC.

Answer (score 7):

Once the file is generated, you can run

```
set-content FILENAME.csv ((get-content FILENAME.csv) -replace '"')
```

Comment: This deserves to be the answer. Thank you sop much

Comment: If I have a CSV line with three parameters like `"123", "Sanchez, Rick", "Scientist"`, this turns it into four parameters.  Subsequent input processes will fail to import correctly.

Comment: @Tony isn't that 4 parameters? Which error do you get?

Comment: @Tiago It's three: ID, Name, and Job title.  Name just happens to include a comma separator it its text.  Let's say Job Title was "Vice President of Science, Technology, and Logistics".  Stripping away the quotes turned that single column into three.

Comment: @Tony you can replace the comma between double quotes with any other character like an hyphen (-) before removing the double quotes. [There's a solution here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/76ea2473-9a49-4037-a720-76aa8fa47663/replace-commas-present-in-quotes-in-a-csv-file?forum=winserverpowershell) which suggests this, `$Pattern = '(?<!"".+),(?!.+"")'
$Text = '"abc, 123"'
$Text -replace $Pattern , '-'`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how pathological (or "full-featured") your CSV data is, one of the posted solutions will already work.

The solution posted by Kory Gill is almost perfect - the only issue remaining is that quotes are removed also for cells containing the line separator `\r\n`, which is causing issues in many tools.

The solution is adding a newline to the character class expression:

```
$fixedData = $quotedData | % {$_ -replace  `
'\G(?<start>^|,)(("(?<output>[^,"\n]*?)"(?=,|$))|(?<output>".*?(?<!")("")*?"(?=,|$)))' `
,'${start}${output}'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this for my needs:

```
function ConvertTo-Delimited {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)]
        [psobject[]]$InputObject,
        [string]$Delimiter='|',
        [switch]$ExcludeHeader
    )
    Begin {

        if ( $ExcludeHeader -eq $false ) {
            @(
                $InputObject[0].PsObject.Properties | `
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            ) -Join $Delimiter          
        }

    }
    Process {

        foreach ($item in $InputObject) {
            @(
                $item.PsObject.Properties | `
                Select-Object Value | `
                ForEach-Object { 
                    if ( $null -ne $_.Value ) {$_.Value.ToString()} 
                    else {''} 
                }
            ) -Join $Delimiter
        }

    }
    End {}

}
```

Usage:

```
$Data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        A = $null
        B = Get-Date
        C = $null
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        A = 1
        B = Get-Date
        C = 'Lorem'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        A = 2
        B = Get-Date
        C = 'Ipsum'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        A = 3
        B = $null
        C = 'Lorem Ipsum'
    }
)

# with headers
PS> ConvertTo-Delimited $Data
A|B|C
1|7/17/19 9:07:23 PM|Lorem
2|7/17/19 9:07:23 PM|Ipsum
||

# without headers
PS> ConvertTo-Delimited $Data -ExcludeHeader
1|7/17/19 9:08:19 PM|Lorem
2|7/17/19 9:08:19 PM|Ipsum
||
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | 
    foreach { $_ -replace '^"|"$|"(?=,)|(?<=,)"','' }
```

This replaces matches with the empty string, in each line. Breaking down the regex above:

- `|` is like an OR, used to unite the following 4 sub-regexes
- `^"` matches quotes in the beginning of the line
- `"$` matches quotes in the end of the line
- `"(?=,)` matches quotes that are immediately followed by a comma
- `(?<=,)"` matches quotes that are immediately preceded by a comma

Answer (score 1):

I found that Kory's answer didn't work for the case where the original string included more than one blank field in a row.  I.e. "ABC",,"0" was fine but "ABC",,,"0" wasn't handled properly.  It stopped replacing quotes after the ",,,".  I fixed it by adding "`|(?<output>)`" near the end of the first parameter, like this:

```
% {$_ -replace  `
    '\G(?<start>^|,)(("(?<output>[^,"]*?)"(?=,|$))|(?<output>".*?(?<!")("")*?"(?=,|$))|(?<output>))', `
    '${start}${output}'}
```

Comment: Nice, this took care of my data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't spent much time looking for removing the quotes. But, here is a workaround.

```
get-process | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Verbose -Path $env:temp\test.csv
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $env:temp\test.csv
```

This is a quick workaround and there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: I still get quotes using it.

Comment: I'm not sure a workaround for what. Was there something other than removing quotes from the file in the OP question?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified variant of JPBlanc's answer:

I had an existing csv file which looked like this:

```
001,002,003
004,005,006
```

I wanted to export only the first and third column to a new csv file. And for sure I didn't want any quotes ;-)
It can be done like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\source.csv -Delimiter ',' -Header A,B,C | select A,C | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' | % {$_ -replace '"',''} | Out-File -Encoding utf8 .\target.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer to a similar question so I'm posting what I've found here...

For **exporting as Pipe Delimited** with No Quotes for string qualifiers, use the following:

```
$objtable | convertto-csv -Delimiter "|" -notypeinformation | select -Skip $headers | % { $_ -replace '"\|"', "|"} | % { $_ -replace '""', '"'} | % { $_ -replace "^`"",''} | % { $_ -replace "`"$",''} | out-file "$OutputPath$filename" -fo -en ascii
```

This was the only thing I could come up with that could handle quotes and commas within the text; especially things like a quote and comma next to each other at the beginning or ending of a text field.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a powershell csv object from the pipeline and outputs like convertto-csv but without adding quotes (unless needed).

```
function convertto-unquotedcsv {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$csv, $delimiter=',', [switch]$noheader=$false)
    begin {
      $NeedQuotesRex = "($([regex]::escape($delimiter))|[\n\r\t])"
      if ($noheader) { $names = @($true) } else { $names = @($false) }
    } 
    process {
      $psop = $_.psobject.properties
      if (-not $names) {
        $names = $psop.name | % {if ($_ -match $NeedQuotesRex) {'"' + $_ + '"'} else {$_}}
        $names -join $delimiter   # unquoted csv header
      }
      $values = $psop.value | % {if ($_ -match $NeedQuotesRex) {'"' + $_ + '"'} else {$_}}
      $values -join $delimiter    # unquoted csv line
    } 
    end {
    }
}
```

$names gets an array of noteproperty names and $values gets an array of notepropery values. It took that special step to output the header. The process block gets the csv object one piece at a time.

Here is a test run

```
$delimiter = ','; $csvData = @"
id,string,notes,"points per 1,000",number
4,"a delimiter$delimiter is in here,","test data 3",1,348
5,"a comma, is in here,","test data 4`r`nwith a newline",0.5,347
6,hello world2.,classic,"3,000",123
"@

$csvdata | convertfrom-csv | sort number | convertto-unquotedcsv -delimiter $delimiter

id,string,notes,"points per 1,000",number
6,hello world2.,classic,"3,000",123
5,"a comma, is in here,","test data 4
with a newline",0.5,347
4,"a delimiter, is in here,",test data 3,1,348
```