# How to replace " on a CSV in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

If I got a CSV file and there are a lot of strings that contain exactly `"Name"`.

How do I get to have only Name and not "Name"? `-replace` won't work as you can't quote the quotes:

```
$computername.Name = $computername.Name -replace (""", "")    # won't work
```

edit: example csv export Name,"IPAddress"
SVDCO03,"10.10.15.46"
SVLIC01,"10.10.20.221"
 where i need to get those quotas away

Comment: Post the full snippet of code. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please show sample content of your CSV and the code you use to read it.

Comment: What is the real goal?  Does Import-csv strip out the offending quotes for you, or not?  Are you trying to do something else, like load the CSV data into Excel?

Comment: The CSV is loaded in another programm where the quotas are making trouble, as i export to the csv file there are quotas which i need to get rid off

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24074205/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

not sure why u are trying to parse the csv you can actually quote the quotes :)

enclose the double quotes inside single and use the regex replace

```
"name" -replace '"'
```

or use the string replace method.

```
"name".replace('"','')
```

Comment: oh well nevermind didnt got this in mind, and i try to parse it cause it is used further on somewhere else where they need it like this but thx for the quick and ease answer

Comment: The example would be better as  '"name"' -replace '"'

Comment: The example you gave strips the commas even before the replace happens.