# Concatenating Two Properties from a Select-Object Statement

Tags: powershell

I am selecting the DisplayName and DisplayVersion properties of an installed application like so:

```
$response = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*My Application*'} | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

The result is: `My Application 1.2`

For additional parsing purposes I need to concatenate the result with a pipe character so it returns as: `My Application|1.2`

However I'm unable to find the right syntax.

Comment: Use `-ExpandProperty` on `Select-Object` instead of piping to `Format-Table`, and then you can do `$response -join '|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*office*'} | Select-Object @{Expression={$_.DisplayName + "|" + $_.DisplayVersion}} | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

**Using -join:**

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*office*'} | Select-Object @{Expression={$_.DisplayName, $_.DisplayVersion -join "|"}} | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

**Excursus with ConvertTo-CSV**

You could use ConvertTo-CSV, but if you require having no header, you need to use -skip 1, which may not always be comprehensible. Additionally, you may have to [remove quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074205/convertto-csv-output-without-quotes) from the output, which is an additional effort.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*| Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*office*'} | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | ConvertTo-Csv  -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation | select -skip 1
```

Comment: While this might work it is encouraging bad coding practices. Don't save the output of format-table.... You could use `join` or even `ConvertTo-CSV` if you really wanted.

Comment: Variant with -join added

Answer (score 5):

Use a calculated property to combine the two single properties:

```
$response = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  
  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*My Application*'} | 
    Select-Object  @{n='DisplayNameVersion';e={$_.DisplayName,$_.DisplayVersion -join '|'}}).DisplayNameVersion
```