# Update Status Field on CSV and Export again

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm developing a script for creating a navigation in SharePoint with PnP. For this purpose I created a CSV with my URLS and some addional informations.

My CSV looks like this:

```
Name,ParentName,Level,URL,Status,Order
Tools,Consulting,1,http://linkless.header/,Existing,3
Tool Wiki,Tools,2,http://linkless.header/,Existing,3
Tool Box,Tools,2,http://linkless.header/,add,2
Tool Development,Tools,2,https://linkless.header/,Remove,1
```

I import the CSV with following command

```
$CURRENT_DIRECTORY=Get-Location
$CSV_Navigation = Import-Csv $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv
```

Then I want to make a few changes and export it again.

```
$STATUS_ADD="Add"
$STATUS_REMOVE="Remove"
$STATUS_EXISTING="Existing"

function setStatusInCSV {
    ForEach($Item in $CSV_Navigation) {
        If ($Item.Status -eq $STATUS_ADD) {
            $Item.Status = $STATUS_EXISTING
        }   
    }
    Export-Csv $CSV_Navigation -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

For this I get the following Error

```
Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Char' required by parameter 'Delimiter'. Specified method is not supported.
At Path\Navigation\UpdateNavigation.ps1:95 char:16
+     Export-Csv $CSV_Navigation -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigatio ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

If I run the command with a delimiter it looks like this:

```
Export-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At Path\Navigation\UpdateNavigation.ps1:95 char:5
+     Export-Csv $CSV_Navigation -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigatio ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

My $CSV_Navigation looks like this

```
Write-Host $CSV_Navigation 
@{Name=Tools; ParentName=Consulting; Level=1; URL=http://linkless.header/; Status=Ex
isting; Order=3} @{Name=Tool Wiki; ParentName=Tools; Level=2; URL=http://linkless.header/; Status=Existing; Order=3} @{Name=Tool Box; ParentName=Tools; Level=2; URL=http://linkless.header/; Status=Existing; Order=2} @{Name=Tool Development; ParentName=Tools; Leve
l=2; URL=https://linkless.header/; Status=Remove; Order=1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is the positional parameter of this command.

you need to define what your input objetc is. Like this:

```
Export-Csv -InputObject $CSV_Navigation -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit:** You need to use `Select-Object -Property YourPropeerties` to get the right output or pipe your array to the command:

```
$CSV_Navigation | Export-Csv -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, If I define the InputObject like in your example, I get only the properties of the Object not the content.  ```"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"8","8","8","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"```

Comment: If I pipe with Select Object I get the correct csv, but all examples have "" arround them
```$CSV_Navigation | Select-Object -Property Name,ParentName,Level,URL,Status,Order | Export-Csv -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv  -NoTypeInformation 
``` 
Like _"Tool Box","Tools","2","http://linkless.header/","Existing","2"_

Comment: try: $CSV_Navigation |  Export-Csv -Path $CURRENT_DIRECTORY\UrlsNavigation.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: It is the same like Select-Object. I have this ```"Tool Development","Tools","2","https://linkless.header/","Remove","1"```

Comment: You find similar questions on SO how to remove the double quotas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074205/convertto-csv-output-without-quotes