Prefix lines of a CSV with a string but after every 99 lines, use another string
This is based on another thread.  I didn't want to muddy that one with another question as that one was already solved.
Basically, I got burned by the system into which these CSVs get pulled.  I think I can improve upon the sorted process.  Rather than prepending a number to each item, I think I can make it easier by prepending a unique string for every 99 items.  Based on the example from the other thread, let me show you what I mean...
import.csv
Name,Number
John Smith,(555)123-4567
Jane Smith,(555)123-4567
Todd Smith,(555)123-4567
...
Jeremy Smith,(555)123-4567
...
Gen Smith,(555)123-4567

In the sample data above, Jeremy is on line 100 and Gen is on line 198 or something...
desired_output.csv
Name,Number
10000-JohnSmith,5551234567
10000-JaneSmith,5551234567
10000-ToddSmith,5551234567
...
10001-JeremySmith,5551234567
...
10002-GenSmith,5551234567

The idea would be that, after every 99 lines, the prefix increased by 1 so the users could easily be grouped.  I'm sure the old script, mentioned in the other thread by @santiago-squarzon, cannot be fully recycled.  But the import and export I think would remain the same.

Seems like something like this could work, assuming all output is going to a single file:
$sample = @'
Name,Number
John Smith,(555)123-4567
Jane Smith,(555)123-4567
Todd Smith,(555)123-4567
Jeremy Smith,(555)123-4567
Gen Smith,(555)123-4567
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$groupSize = 3 # This would be 99 using the original CSV
$index = 0     # Don't touch this one
$chunk = 10000 # This one either

$sample | ForEach-Object {
    if ($index++ -eq $groupSize) {
        $chunk++
        $index = 0
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name   = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + $_.Name
        Number = $_.Number -replace '\D'
    }
}

The example above would output:
Name               Number    
----               ------    
10000-John Smith   5551234567
10000-Jane Smith   5551234567
10000-Todd Smith   5551234567
10001-Jeremy Smith 5551234567
10001-Gen Smith    5551234567

If this is what you're after, for the actual CSV you would be using Import-Csv to read it and only need to change the $groupSize to 99:
$csvPath = "$Env:OneDriveCommercial\Desktop\master2.csv"
$CsvOutput = "$Env:OneDriveCommercial\Desktop\master3.csv"

$groupSize = 99
$index = 0     # Don't touch this one
$chunk = 10000 # This one either

Import-Csv $csvPath | ForEach-Object {
    if ($index++ -eq $groupSize) {
        $chunk++
        $index = 0
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name   = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + $_.Name
        Number = $_.Number -replace '\D'
    }
} | Export-Csv $CsvOutput -NoTypeInformation

If you also want to remove the white spaces from each .Name then you can use:
Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '\s')

Or if you want to remove anything that is not characters in the English Alphabet you can use:
Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '[^a-z]')


I've edited my first post and added the code I'm currently using.  So, thanks for that!  It's spitting out a CSV with the prefixes but not much else.  No errors though.   I'll edit the original post above to see if I can add a screenshot of what it gives me.

So don't use Get-Content there, in $csvContent | ForEach-Object { you just do Import-Csv $csvPath | ForEach-Object {... then it should work ;) I'll edit my answer

nice catch!  Not sure how I failed to see that I needed an Import-Csv.  Think All I need to do now is strip the occasional comma from the names in the output.  Guessing that needs to go into the name section of the pscustomobject?

yeah, the ($_.Name -replace '\s') will only remove white spaces tho, producing the output exactly as you shared in your question @RKillcrazy. Export-Csv already converts these objects into CSV format so no need to take care of commas.

That's the thing; the Output file shows names like 10000-ANSELL,PERRY so, the comma is still there.  I tried doing something like adding what you did in the other thread ($NamePattern = '[^a-zA-Z]') and then calling the variable via Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '\s') + ($_.Name -replace $NamePattern).

There is no need for 2 replacements, that pattern from your comment already takes care of everything that is not letters: 'ANSELL, PERRY' -replace '[^a-z]' outputs: ANSELLPERRY. Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '[^a-z]') is enough. Is that not working? @RKillcrazy

The last code snippet you shared fixed it.  I replaced Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '\s') with Name = $chunk.ToString() + '-' + ($_.Name -replace '[^a-z]') and that cleaned up the output.

I just noticed something.  While you look at the output in Excel, the data looks good.  However, when you open it in a text editor, each entry has quotes around it.  So, keeping with the aforementioned example, the output looks like "10000-ANSELLPERRY","XXXYYYZZZZ".  Obvioulsy, the last part is the phone number but hidden.  The point is, I'm getting quotes in there so I can't use the file.  Now, I'm trying to figure out where they're coming from.

@RKillcrazy this is something that Export-Csv does by default. The "..." are to safely convert objects to CSV that could contain commas. If you don't want the quotes you can use Export-Csv -UseQuotes Never however this parameter is only available in PowerShell 7. If you're in PowerShell 5.1 you can use one of the alternatives shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074205/convertto-csv-output-without-quotes

I would have loved to been able to have gone down the -UseQuotes Never path but I'm stuck with PS v5.1.  Maybe next time!  For now, I added another line below your Export-Csv line above.  I used Set-Content "$CsvOutput" ((Get-Content "$CsvOutput") -replace '"') and the data looks good.  Testing its usability now but, I think it'll work just fine.

Here, this should work pretty well and easy to read.
A simple For() updating the value of the Name property with a If to check the grouping
$GroupId = 10000
$GroupLimit = 99

$Csv = Import-Csv -Path $CsvImportPath 

for ($Index = 0; $Index -lt $Csv.Count; $Index++) {
    if (0 -eq ($index % $GroupLimit)) { $GroupId++ }
    $Csv[$Index].Name = '{0}-{1}' -f $GroupId, $Csv[$index].Name
    $Csv[$Index].Number = $Csv[$index].Number
}

$Csv | Export-Csv -Path $CsvExportPath -NoTypeInformation

